# TypeError: Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I am making text preprocessing but it is challenging, can someone explain why I have the type

error? I check the type of the column it is int,  so what is the wrong with the code?

I am using Jupiter notebook.

```
fav = df[['favourites_count','text']].sort_values('favourites_count',
           ascending = False)[:5].reset_index()
for i in range(5):
    print(i, fav['text'][i],'\n')
```

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to your column `favourites_count` having mixed data types. I suggest you convert it to numeric before sorting:

```
df['favourites_count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['favourites_count'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you sort your dataframe df along your column "favourites_count", the sorting algorithm compares the values in along that column.

As it compares one numeric value with other numeric value, it should have came accros a value which is not a "int" data type.

Check the type of the column with following syntax:

```
df["favourites_count"].dtypes
```

If the output says

```
dtype('O')
```

That means the data in the column is mixed data.

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833412/13905190, convert the datatype of "favourites_count" into numeric datatype using "pd.to_numeric()" function.

Now if you check the "dtypes" of your column, it should output:

```
dtype('int64')
```

Since you successfully converted the datatype of the numeric column, you can sort it without any errors.